# C# help in classes

Tags: c#, .net, class

I have two classes, `SuperHero` and `SuperTeam`. How can I add instances of `SuperHero` to the `TeamList` property of `SuperTeam`?

```
namespace SuperLeague
{
    class SuperHero
    {           
        string SuperHeroName;
        string ComicTitle;

        public SuperHero()
        {
            SuperHeroName = "";
            ComicTitle = "";
        }

        public SuperHero(string nSuperHeroName,string nComicTitle)
        {
            SuperHeroName = nSuperHeroName;
            ComicTitle = nComicTitle;
        }

        public string nSuperHeroName
        {
            get { return SuperHeroName; }
            set { SuperHeroName = nSuperHeroName; }
        }

        public string nComicTitle
        {
            get { return ComicTitle; }
            set { ComicTitle = nComicTitle; }
        }

    }

    class SuperTeam
    {
        string SuperTeamName;
        List<SuperTeam> TeamList = new List<SuperTeam>();

        public SuperTeam()
        {
            SuperTeamName = "";
        }

        public SuperTeam(string nSuperTeamName)
        {
            SuperTeamName = nSuperTeamName;
        }

        public string nSuperTeamName
        {
            get { return SuperTeamName; }
            set { SuperTeamName = nSuperTeamName; }
        }

        public void SuperTeamAdd(SuperHero NewHero)
        {
            TeamList.Add(NewHero);
        }

        public void SuperTeamRemove(string NameToFind)
        {
            SuperHero SuperHeroToDel = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < TeamList.Count; i++)
            {
                if (TeamList[i].nSuperHeroName.Equals(NameToFind))
                {
                    SuperHeroToDel = TeamList[i];
                    TeamList.Remove(SuperHeroToDel);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: guessing here due to 'no clear question'. but your team class defines "List<SuperTeam> TeamList = new List<SuperTeam>();", i think you want a  "List<SuperHero> TeamList = new List<SuperHero>();"

Comment: First of all, you should set your fields (like `SuperHeroName`) to private. And, more importantly, your setters should be `SuperHeroName = value` instead of `SuperHeroName = nSuperHeroName`. Your setters won't do anything as they stand.

Comment: @dcastro fields are private by default.

Comment: @clcto they look fine now, but before the post was edited, it showed `public string SuperHeroName`.

Comment: @MarvinSmit Shouldnt SuperHero be added at the above class ?? I want to make a list with teams names , each team name contains SuperHero members ,what i want to do is to add SuperHero members in that list so i can later in my main call different instances (for example team1, team2 and team3 with each one containing some members from SuperHero . i dont know if you can undresrtand me .. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the provided code;

- Your SuperHero class represents a single hero.
- Your SuperTeam class represents a single team which contains a list of hero's.

If you want multiple team's with super hero's we'll need another container. Something like

```
List<SuperTeam> listOfTeams;
```

This will allow you to store multiple "SuperHero"'s into the "SuperTeam", and store multiple teams in "listOfTeams"

Since you mention you want to get a team used on it's name, you could also use a "`Dictionary<string, SuperTeam> CollectionOfTeams`". This will allow you to get a team from 'CollectionOfTeams' using the a key.

```
SuperHero superMan = new SuperHero();
// fill in superMan properties
SuperTeam flyingTeam = new SuperTeam();
flyingTeam.members.Add(superMan);
// add more super hero members that fly to the team
collectionOfTeams.Add("Flying", flyingTeam);


// Getting the 'flying team'

SuperTeam currentTeam = CollectionOfTeams["Flying"];
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Ok , i did understand the first part of your answer about the extra list i need to make but i dont quite understand the second part , if you could give me a reference about it or explain it a little bit better :) .

Comment: If you use a list, you'll have to "search through the list" to find the  team with a name. If you use a Dictionary you can get the team using the name directly without having to search for it.

Comment: Do i have to use any extra line of code at the start like Collections.Generic; or it will be fine ??

Comment: If it's not there yet, you can use a 'using' statement. This is to prevent you having to type the entire namespace and class you are using. So without using statement you'll have to type "System.Collection.Generic.Dictionary<string,SuperTeam>", with the "Using System.Collections.Generic;" at the top you only have to type "Dictionary<string,SuperTeam>"

Comment: wow nice , it seems a bit confusing to me as i'm still new at coding but i see that it does saves some lines of code anyway thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
SuperHero hero = new SuperHero();

SuperTeam team = new SuperTeam();

team.TeamList.Add(hero);
```

Also, change the `TeamList` property to this:

```
List<SuperHero> TeamList;
```

Comment: I want to make the TeamList to hold different Names (TeamNames) in which each team name will contain some instances from SuperHero so i can call them later in my Main